# Fortran file dependency with Intel ifort

Tags: module, makefile, fortran, fortran90

I am working in a standard Unix environment, with Intel Fortran 2012 compiler.
since my codes have some old `.f` files and some newer `.f90` files, the makefile is organized in the following structure,

```
f_sources= ... ...
f90_sources= ... ...

f_objects = $(patsubst %.f,%.o,$(f_sources))
f90_objects = $(patsubst %.f90,%.o,$(f90_sources))

$(f_objects): %.o: %.f
        @echo compiling $<
        $(FC) $(FC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# compile f90 files:
$(f90_objects): %.o: %.f90
        @echo compiling $<
        $(FC) $(FC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

The problem is, few strange `.f` files depend on the modules defined in some `.f90` files, and then the compiler seems not able to detect the dependency since I compile first all the `.f` files...

```
Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Since `use a_module` is not valid FORTRAN77 why/how have you got `.f` files which depend on modules defined in `.f90` files ?

Comment: If you have files that depend on other files then you need to tell make about that with prerequisite information. That's not specific to fortran in any way.

Comment: @EtanReisner in this specific case, suppose we have only one such strange .f file, could you suggest a nice way to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
f77_file_with_module_dependency.o: f90_file_for_module.o
```

to your Makefile somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have a `there.f` file that depends on `mod_here.f90`, you declare in your makefile the following:

```
there.o: mod_here.o
      $(FC) $(FC_FLAG) -c there.f -o there.o
```

When the makefile gets to this file, `there.f`, it will see that it depends on `mod_here.f90`, which hasn't yet been compiled, so it'll compile it.

Comment: There's no reason to duplicate the rule for building the file he only needs the prereq indicated.

Comment: @EtanReisner: News to me :D. I usually do it as I've posted, never thought to try it without declaring the rule again.